# how to call a google script function from html

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am a newbie with HTML and fair at google apps scripting.
I am trying to call a gas function using a button in html.
When the function is called it gives this fault

> "Uncaught Error: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null.  at Data (Data:29) 
>   (Lineup)"

It appears to fault out at the first line of the code.
I've searched around various places and I can not find why this is causing an error.
Here is the code snippets:

### HTML

```
     <input type="button" id="br" value="Order Complete" 
     onClick="Data(3,22)"> 
     <script>
     function Data(row,col){

     google.script.run

     .Data(row,col);
     }
     </script>
```

### Code:

```
    function Data(row,col) {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Lineup"); // this 
        is line 29 where it is faulting
      var history =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("completed");
      var data = ss.getRange(row+2,col-5,1,5).getValues();
```

Comment: If you are running the code from the code editor, there is no active spreadsheet.  But I don't know If that is your case.  How is the code being triggered to run?

Comment: I am deploying it as a web app (from the code editor); I had a Logger.log(row,col), in place to verify  it was passing the information and it faulted there also (first of the code- so I removed the logger; and it still faulted).

Comment: The add-on may have lost it's authorization.  Remove the add-on and re-install it.  This is probably a bug in Apps Script.

Comment: Bound script? If not, you can't call `getActive()`

Comment: It is a bound script; I'll try to remove/reinstall add-on.  Thanks